# Facebook login php how to log out just from the app itself

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-login

I am trying to log users out from my website while they are using facebook login.

I am using "Facebook login php sdk v5".

i used fb-callback to log in:

```
<?php
session_start();
# login-callback.php
require_once 'facebook-sdk-v5/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'app_secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
  // Logged in!
  $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
  header('Location: index.php');

  // Now you can redirect to another page and use the
  // access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
}
?>
```

so i guees to check if some one is logged in i just check if the $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] is set but to log them out do i "manually" put null inside the $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']?

Comment: Show us your code, and what you have tried in regards to your problem. (providing a [mcve])

Comment: @nytrix edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you paste how you log your users it would be helpful. I will assume you use default example code from facebook (FB) for login with their php sdk. It works sending a request to a RESTful api (from your server to facebook graph api) so theres actually no session (RESTful approach), everything is managed through an access_token. When a user logs in to your site through FB, it passes to your callback URL a response wich contains an access_token field, then you can use that access_token only once, generally to get FB user's profile, then you validate that information to log in your user in your server. Why all this explanation? because you should understand how this process works.

The short answer to this is, you handle the logout manually (Session::destroy() for example), you don't need the FB php sdk for logout

Comment: i edited my question and i showed my code, so my question is if ill put null instead of $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'], is it enough, considering that im validating if a user is logged in only if the $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] is set. 2) can a hacker put data inside $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] (with cookie editing) than my way is not secure enough, what steps should i take to validate that the user is logged in instead of checking $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']?

Comment: Probably you should learn some PHP framework, they handle this stuff and includes security by default, and also makes your app with a cleanner structure. There is no totally secure app, and with that should be enough to log out a user, if you want extra security you should validate the token with FB when a user logs in and see if it is valid and non expired token

Comment: so in each page that i want to be shown only for users i need to validate the token all over again if i want a high security? because just confirming if the $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] is set isnt enough? just answer me this please

Comment: The answer depends on your needs, it should be enough for most situations, but just having that security check isn't a good approach, but again, it depends how much security you want to implement. 
And no, I was talking about checking if the access_token is valid whenever you are going to do some important changes, like inserts or deletes in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Logging People Out

You can log people out of your app by undoing whatever login status indicator you added, for example deleting the session that indicates a person is logged in. You should also remove the stored access token.

Logging someone out is not the same as revoking login permission (removing previously granted authentication), which can be performed separately. Because of this, build your app so it doesn't automatically force people who have logged out back to the Login dialog.

(THANKS FACEBOOK DOCS)